# How do they get the guns from the stock room to the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix* Neo and Trinity are in a program that shows a stockroom of guns:

How do they get the guns into the Matrix? From what I can see, they are two completely different places.

Comment: It's all in the Matrix...that's **one** place. The stockroom, if you like, is a subroutine. It's like where do their clothes come from.

Comment: The guns get in the same way the people get it - by hacking the system.  The stockroom is just a sort of interactive menu to let you choose what to take.

Comment: Think of it like playing a multiplayer FPS. You find a game, pick your loadout, then spawn in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the conceits of the Matrix films is that you can, in the [construct](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Construct) program, load anything you want and then take it directly into the Matrix. There's also evidence that it works in reverse, allowing information and [objects](http://www.therpf.com/showthread.php?t=158099) from the Matrix to be taken back into the Construct for further analysis.

> **Morpheus:** *This...is the Construct. It's our loading program. We can load anything, from clothing...to equipment...weapons...training
>   simulations...anything we need.*

Other examples include [Trinity's motorbike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zToCNweoT8w&feature=youtu.be&t=6s) in Matrix Reloaded (going in) or the data tapes in [Final Flight of the Osiris](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Flight_of_the_Osiris) (coming out).

Answer (score 4):

The "stock room", which is called the [Construct](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Construct), is a staging area for the digital items (like the guns) used by the Zion operatives -- it is *not* part of the Matrix itself. As Morpheus explained to Neo:

> It's our loading program. We can load anything from clothing...to equipment...weapons...training simulations...anything we need.
>
> <sub>***The Matrix***</sub>

The code comprising these digital items still needs to be inserted into the Matrix, and this must be done in the same way as the operatives jack themselves into the Matrix: as Morpheus explained, a "pirate signal" is broadcast by the hovership's core, and this signal contains the code necessary to hack into the Matrix. The signal also transmits the information necessary to jack the operatives into the Matrix along with their equipment (guns, etc.). The connection to the Matrix must also be bidirectional -- the falling green code seen on the hovership monitors contains information *from* the Matrix.<sup>1</sup>

Since the Construct is separate from the Matrix, it is a safe place for the operatives to train in a Matrix-like environment free from dangers like the Agents. It also allows them to choose their equipment (e.g. which particular weapons to arm themselves with) and prepare for jacking into the Matrix.

As an analogy to [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), the Construct is a program that calls the [constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) of the digital equipment to create [instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)) of each item. Zion operatives can set constructed items to the desired state in the safety of the Construct before entering the Matrix (for example, when Neo cocks the [MP5K](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/MP5K#Heckler_.26_Koch_MP5K) in the stock room scene so that it is ready to fire as soon as he enters the Matrix).

---

<sup>1</sup>The code for the guns themselves probably originated from the Matrix, as the machines would have written the code for guns for use in the Matrix (e.g. by the police). This is in contrast to, say, the [Woman in Red](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Woman_in_Red) which was written by Mouse and therefore originated from the Zion rebels.

Comment: To be picky, the analogy doesn't really work because the problem noted in the question is not object construction but _allocation_ of and access to the memory representing those objects. It's basically "how does the Construct implement IPC with the Matrix" :)